# how to create an admin user when writing a django app

Tags: python, django

using docs.djangoproject.com "Writing your first Django app part 2", and for some reason, at the Introducing the Django Admin section, it won't let me enter any characters in the password field. Any errors that could cause this?

I've tried starting over and following the instructions again, but get the the same results.

**Screenshot of what I see**:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The password field is hidden. It still registers your key inputs but it doesn't show it. Enter your password and press enter and it will proceed with the admin creating process.

Answer (score 1):

The password is hidden, but the input is still recorded. It's supposed to be like that.